# How do I calculate space between two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I calculate the amount of space between one element and the next rendered element?

I want to find out how much space is between a specific `hr` and whatever shows below it. Visually that could be a paragraph or a heading or an image or anything else, but the `hr` and the next thing could both be nested within other blocks. So, by "rendered element" I mean the next visible thing on the page.

The reason I need this is that I need to insert an element after the `hr`, `position: relative`, and I don't want to shift the content down unless the space I have is shorter than my new element. If the space is shorter, I only want to shift the content down as much as necessary to avoid covering content.

I don't have any control over the generation of the HTML at all. I can only add code to a generated page.

Here's an example of HTML that I'm working with:

```html
<div class="extra-wrapper">
    <p>The line that separates the header from the rest of the page is below this.</p>
    <hr>
</div>
<p class="top-p">
    Lorem ipsum dolor...
</p>
```

If it was always like that, the snippet below might work, but the problem is that both the element that I'm starting with and the next element visible on the page might be nested within other blocks in unpredictable ways.

It also occurs to me that the next element might be a sibling. So I need to check if `$hr.next()` has a value, which I'm not doing in the snippet below.

```js
$(function() {
  var $header = $('#header');
  var $hr = $header.siblings('.extra-wrapper').children('hr').filter(':first');
  var $next_element = $hr.parent().next();

  var extra_wrapper_bottom_margin = parseInt($hr.parent().css('margin-bottom'));
  var extra_wrapper_bottom_padding = parseInt($hr.parent().css('padding-bottom'));

  var hr_bottom_margin = parseInt($hr.css('margin-bottom'));
  var hr_bottom_padding = parseInt($hr.css('padding-bottom'));

  var next_element_top_margin = parseInt($next_element.css('margin-top'));
  var next_element_top_padding = parseInt($next_element.css('padding-top'));

  /* Account for collapsing vertical margins. */
  var biggest_margin;
  if (extra_wrapper_bottom_margin > hr_bottom_margin) {
    biggest_margin = extra_wrapper_bottom_margin;
  } else {
    biggest_margin = hr_bottom_margin;
  }

  if (next_element_top_margin > biggest_margin) {
    biggest_margin = next_element_top_margin;
  }

  var space_between = biggest_margin + hr_bottom_padding + extra_wrapper_bottom_padding + next_element_top_padding;

  $('#space').val(space_between);
});
```

```css
div.extra-wrapper {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
div.extra_wrapper hr {
  margin: 1em;
}
p.top-p {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <p>This is the header content.</p>
</div>
<div class="extra-wrapper">
  <hr>
</div>
<p class="top-p">
  Lorem ipsum dolor...
</p>
<label>Space:
  <input id="space" type="text">
</label>
```

Comment: As you're using jQuery, you have access to `offset()`, which gets the current coordinates of the element relative to the document. All you really have to do is get the offset of both elements, and subtract

Comment: @adeneo That would get me the space between the tops of the two elements. I need the space between the bottom of the first element and the top of the second. However, using `offset()` might save me a little work. Maybe I don't need to worry about however the elements are nested if I can accurately measure the height of the element. I've been playing around with this in [a pen](http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/vLVpMR) and it doesn't look like jQuery can do this, but I can get it with the `offsetHeight` DOM element property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the `offset().top` values of the two elements (as indicated by @adeneo and @georg) and subtract the height of the first element. I don't need to calculate the borders, margins, and padding myself.

It wasn't as difficult to find the next element as I originally thought it would be.

Determining the height of the first element isn't too tricky, but neither `height()` nor `innerHeight()` will do it. I have to use the property [`offsetHeight`](http://devdocs.io/dom/htmlelement/offsetheight) on the DOM element.

I need something like this:

```js
var space = $next.offset().top - ($hr.offset().top + $hr[0].offsetHeight)`
```

I wouldn't have been able to figure this out if it weren't for the comment by @adeneo and the answer by @georg, but neither one provided a full solution.

The following example also has a slightly more detailed version at CodePen: [calculate space between two elements](http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/vLVpMR)

```js
var find_next = function($el) {
  $next = $el.next();
  while ( !$next.length ) {
    find_next($el.parent());
  }
  return $next;
}

$(window).load(function() {
  var $header = $('#header');
  var $hr = $header.siblings('.extra-wrapper').find('hr');
  var $after_header = find_next($hr);
  
  var hr_top = $hr.offset().top;
  var hr_bottom = $hr[0].offsetHeight + hr_top;
  var after_header_top = $after_header.offset().top;
  var space_between = after_header_top - hr_bottom;
  
  $('.space-between').css({
    'top': hr_bottom,
    'height': space_between,
    'line-height': space_between + 'px'
  });
  $('.space-between .info').text(space_between + 'px');  
});
```

```css
div.extra-wrapper {
  margin: 1em;
}

div.extra-wrapper hr {
  margin: 1em;
}

p.top-p {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

div.space-between {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-color: #f0f;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <p>This is the header section with the logo.</p>
  <h1 class="logo"><a href="#0"><img alt="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/people"></a></h1>
</div>
<div class="page-divider"></div>
<div class="extra-wrapper">
  <hr>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p class="top-p">
    Lorem ipsum dolor ...
  </p>
</div>

<div class="space-between">
  <span class="info">Space between: </span>
<div class="show-position-info"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```js
next = function($el) {
  while($el.length) {  
    var s = $el.next();
    if (s.length) return s;
    $el = $el.parent();
  }
}

hr = $('hr');

alert(next(hr).offset().top - hr.offset().top)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
<div>
  <div class="extra-wrapper">
      <p>The line.... this.</p>
      <hr>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<p class="top-p">
    Lorem ipsum dolor...
</p>
```

Comment: In your example, the bottom margin of the `hr` is 8 and the top margin of the `p` is 16, so the value I'm looking for should be 16 (because of collapsing vertical margins). This reports a value of about 18. Actually, the alert I got said 17.599998474121094.

I think it's because it's calculating the difference between the tops of the two different elements and the calculated value includes the height of the `hr` which is apparently about 2px. I need the difference between the bottom of the first element and the top of the next element.